# Como mandar notificaciones push entre paginas php y jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, push, notification

Hola amigos tengo una duda que no se como resolver, no se si usar firebase o alguna lógica con jquery, tengo un crud, pero quiero que al enviar un nuevo registro a la base de datos desde el portal de usuarios que muestro a continuación
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le llegue una notificación en tiempo real al portal de la administración y si se puede que sea web push con sonido.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como hacerlo, si con un while que maneje un estatus, son como las notificaciones de facebook, yo yo le doy like a una foto de mi amigo, le llega a él una notificación de que le dieron like, algo así quiero.

Comment: Parece basada en opiniones.

Comment: @Bicho lo es! ej de respuesta: pon un timer en la página de administración y que cada n segundos verifique (via ajax) si han habido actualizaciones, en caso afirmativo hace ruido y muestra "humo" en pantalla.

Comment: @quevedo tengo un timer en el datatable que actualiza cada n segundos, pero ahora me dice que no puedo reproducir un sonido hasta que un usuario interactue con la pagina.

Comment: Encontre un video utilizan este elemento a lo mejor te podría ser útil: https://nickersoft.github.io/push.js/

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
//recargar pagina y mostrar resultados
  setInterval(function(){ 
    userDataTable.draw();
    //console.log("Recargado");
   }, 3000);
var userDataTable = $('#userTable').DataTable({
   'serverSide': true,
   'serverMethod': 'post',
   'ajax': {
      'url':'funciones_uuid.php'
   },
   order: [ 0, 'desc' ],
   'columns': [
      { data: 'id' }, { data: 'ticket' },  { data: 'com_usuario' }, { data: 'fecha' }, { data: 'idynombre' }, { data: 'status' }, { data: 'com_admin' }, { data: 'editar' }, { data : 'hanan' },
   ],

Comment: @Cesarin"createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {$('#id_comentario').val(data['id']);
            if ( data['num_status'] == 0 ) {
                 $('td', row).removeClass('bg-warning');$('td', row).removeClass('bg-success');$('td', row).addClass('bg-red');
            }
            if ( data['num_status'] == 1 ) {
                 $('td', row).removeClass('bg-red'); $('td', row).removeClass('bg-success'); $('td', row).addClass('bg-warning'); }
            if ( data['num_status'] == 2 ) {
                 $('td', row).removeClass('bg-red');$('td',
Y falta mas pero esa es la idea

Comment: Recargo la datatable cada cierto tiempo y obtengo un data: status necesito contar cuantos tienen el status = 0 y si hay mas o igual a 1 mandar un push a la admintracion, es lo que quiero hacer, no se si con firebase se me complica mucho.

Comment: ok entonces lo que haces es como recargar el datatable, y tienes un contador de status = 0, y si tienes algun estatus en 1, significa que es nuevo o algo asi ?... te mande una liga donde viene un proyecto denominado push,  lo cheque de un video, yo tambien quiero poner notificaciones en un sistema que estoy haciendo , pero de todos los tutoriales se me han hecho por demas engorrosos

Comment: Algo asi mas o menos me vas entiendo bro, solo que cuando sean status = 0 mandar notificacion pero solo una vez ya que tambien creo un bucle infinito jaja, si es status = 1 no muestra nada, si status = 2 tampoco muestra nada pero si un usuario agrega un registro a mi database entonces ese registro entra con status=0 y ahi deberia mandarme una notificacion a mi como admin. no se como instalar npm en mi pc jaja deja investigo

Comment: Cada que me responden un comentario por aqui aparece en la bandeja un "1" estamos de acuerdo, algo asi quiero.

Comment: Ok, entonces primero tendrías que resolver lo del bucle infinito.  Y luego "checar" si hay 0 y notificas.  te voy a dejar el video de donde saque la liga que te mande, haber si te sirve de algo, me llamo la atención lo de recargar el datatable, pero en mi caso no aplicaría mucho, ya que no estoy manejando entradas de ticket, mas bien dependo de lo que ya esta en BD

Comment: @AlexisMartinez,  mira esta video quizás no resuelva tu problema un ejemplo viéndolo en acción es probable que te  pueda iluminar el día!!.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gb72QlYk9f8    Saludos!!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116214/discussion-between-cesarin-and-alexis-martinez).

Comment: No veo claro lo de **un usuario debe interactuar ...** prueba a ejecutar un click desde done() y en el clik() haces ruido